# Is it possible for Salesforce Platform Events to cross orgs intentionally?

Tags: subscriber, platform-event, org, publisher

Let's say, for whatever reason(s) I have two orgs (maybe not me personally, but two businesses doing business together).

Let's say org A publishes a `Customer_Event__e` (for whatever reasons).

Would it be possible for org B to subscribe to events on org A?

(I mean, WITHOUT creating some proxy on another platform that could catch the event and forward it in some other fashion.)

Comment: For the first time ever, I will concede my question is a duplicate.  BUT, at that time, it seems this was not possible.    Is it correct to assume this isn't changed?  How can I accept this is a duplicate WITHOUT indicating the other question solved my problem?  And what happens when duplicate questions have outdated answers?

Comment: The community's duplicate votes are your indicator that the duplicate question's answer is still believed to be valid.